# Can i write a GUI for fedora using pygtk?

Tags: python, linux, x11, fedora, pygobject

I would like to write my own frontend for an operating system in python my current choice is linux fedora but after the install i would then remove the x window system so that i could write my own OS frontend but would it still work or does pygtk need the x window system to function?

Comment: have you researched pygtk to learn of its dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can run gtk 2 on the framebuffer, so, without X:

http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/gtk-framebuffer.html

Since pygtk seems to use gtk 2, it could work.